# JSP form validation before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

In the JSP page, in the form I have two dropdowns, one for portfolio code and other for rate card code.

Query: When the JSP page gets loaded even though am not selecting the value for portfolio code which is at the top, it always display the alert message for rate card code, that "Please select RateCardCode" while clicking the "save changes" button. which means the last action in the function is always displayed instead of first.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="rateCardCode">RateCardCode</label> 
    <select id="rateCardCode" name="rateCardCode" class="form-control" onchange="bindCode()">   <option value = null label="--SELECT--"> <c:forEach items="${rateCardCodes}" var="rateCardCodes"> <option value="${rateCardCodes.rateCardCode }">${rateCardCodes.rateCardCode}</option> </c:forEach> 
    </select> 
    <!-- <input type="hidden" id="rateCardCode" name="rateCardCode"> --> 
</div >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return validateSearchFields()">
    Save Changes
</button>
```

Before submitting the form, am validating if null is selected the form should not be submitted and alert message should be displayed using the below code:

```
function validateSearchFields() {
    var value = $('#portfolioCode').val();
    if (value == null || value == "")
    {
        alert("Please select Portfolio Name");
        return false;
    }
    value = $('#rateCardCodes').val();
    if (value == null || value == "")
    {
        alert("Please select RateCardCode");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please help me it should display first for portfolio code and next for rate card code.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
<label for="rateCardCode">RateCardCode</label>
<select id="rateCardCode" name="rateCardCode" class="form-control" onchange="bindCode()">       
<option value = null label="--SELECT--">                  
<c:forEach items="${rateCardCodes}" var="rateCardCodes">
         <option value="${rateCardCodes.rateCardCode }">${rateCardCodes.rateCardCode}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select> 
<!-- <input type="hidden" id="rateCardCode" name="rateCardCode"> -->
</div <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return validateSearchFields()">Save Changes</button>.

Comment: Before submitting the form, am validating if null is selected the form should not be submitted and alert message should be displayed using the below code,
function validateSearchFields(){
   
var value = $('#portfolioCode').val();
if (value == null || value == ""){
alert("Please select Portfolio Name");
return false;
}
value = $('#rateCardCodes').val();
if (value == null || value == ""){
alert("Please select RateCardCode");
return false;
}  
return true;  
}

Comment: You should put your code in question section, not the answers.